# Youtube Data API with Kotlin: The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I'm trying to use the Youtube Data API with Kotlin + Spring Boot and I've been struggling a bit.
For now, I'm using hardcoded values for the api_key and the access_token for test purposes.

I'm trying to send a request to list my playlists but I keep getting this error:

```
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden"
  }
],
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
```

Here's my code: 
**Controller:**

```
@RestController
class PlaylistController(
    private val youtubeService: YoutubeService
) {

    @GetMapping("/playlists")
    fun getPlaylists() : YoutubePlaylistResponse {
        return youtubeService.getPlaylists()
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
class YoutubeService(
    private val youtubeClient: YoutubeClient
) {
    fun getPlaylists() = youtubeClient.getPlaylists(
        access_token = "[ACCESS_TOKEN]",
        api_key = "[API_KEY]"
    )
}
```

**Client**

```
@FeignClient(name = "youtube", url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3")
interface YoutubeClient {
    @GetMapping("/playlists")
    fun getPlaylists(
        @RequestHeader("Authorization", required = true) access_token: String,
        @RequestParam("api_key") api_key: String,
        @RequestParam("part") part: String = "snippet",
        @RequestParam("mine") mine: Boolean = true
    ): YoutubePlaylistResponse
}
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I'm getting the acess_token through the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

**Edit:**
I was calling `api_key` but it's actually only `key`.

But now I'm getting a new problem:

```
"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The r... (464 bytes)]] with root cause
```

Apparently, it's because I'm trying to access my playlists and it says that I don't have the permission, but when I do the same request using cURL I get an appropriate response. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You should create your own api key on https://console.cloud.google.com/apis  any tokens created on auth playground are just temporary.  Remember access token is a bearer token.

Comment: I have my own API key, I was just using the playground to easily generate access tokens and I was keeping an eye on the expiration time, but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API documentation, the parameter should be called `key` rather than `api_key`:

> Every request must either specify an API key (with the key parameter) or provide an OAuth 2.0 token. Your API key is available in the Developer Console's API Access pane for your project.

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs

Comment: I suspected a naming issue because the error message from YouTube stated "API key" rather than "api_key", which prompted me to check the docs (been a while since I used the YouTube API). Anyway feel free to accept my answer :-D

Comment: StackOverflow made me wait some time to accept your answer hehe
But now I'm getting a new error, if you could take a look at the edit I made on the post I would be really grateful :)

Comment: You should ask a new question for that

Comment: Need to wait 90 minutes for that :(

Comment: Either way I'm not familiar with that particular error so I'm afraid I can't help you with it